# How to open editor tab context menu using keyboard?

Tags: intellij-idea

Mouse right clicking on the editor tab opens tab context menu (see: [context menu of a tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/managing-editor-tabs.html)).

How to open this context menu using keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [not possible](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6219) to access it via the keyboard.

A workaround would be to use the [Quick Lists](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-quick-lists.html) feature where you can create your own lists of actions and assign this list to the keyboard shortcut.